# Getting complaints about having error 403 from website users

Tags: iis, forbidden, http-status-code-403

My website http://firstlearner.com is running on IIS 7.5 and I'm getting many complaints from website users about the 403 error. And after complaints. when i checked the website it was running fine at my PC. But after 5 minutes of usage i got the same error 403. But when i restarted my internet connection, the site again got running. But other users are still getting the error. I checked the access permissions, they are fine. Please help as I've a new website and losing users is a bad sign.

@Matt
Server log :
Thanks for the reply. I can't change the Server. Let me provide you with a log that got 403 error.

```
'2013-09-19 
23:41:49 
W3SVC118 
PLUTO 
184.173.7.162 
GET 
/favicon.ico 
- 80 
- 103.16.14.72 
HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/29.0.1547.66+Safari/537.36 __utma=41079605.522753606.1379523286.1379523286.1379621581.2;+__utmc=41079605;+__utmz=41079605.1379523286.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) 
- firstlearner.com 
403 501 0 1260 446 499
```

Comment: Your server is responding with a 403: If you can't change the server you can't fix the problem.

Comment: @lain But it's working fine for some users. I have seen the log. Its giving 403 to some and 200 and 304 for some.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a 403 error for many reasons.
See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Are you running IIS on Windows Server?  Since you're running IIS, I wonder if it could be one of these problems:

```
403.9 - Too many users.
403.15 - Client Access Licenses exceeded.
```

I would have a look in the even log to get further information.  Can your run your website on Apache?

---

Edit: try editing the registry key according to this [link](http://www.catalyst.com/kb/100072).  It might be related to the number of open connections which are limited in workstation versions.

Comment: Operating system is WINNT